React router dynamic
I making a application with menu dynamic. I want route dynamic too.
I use toolpad.
My example:
in configureRouters.js
const navigationItems = [    
    { title: "", icon:"",element:"Dashboard", path: '/TestStagionatura/Dashboard' },
    { title: "", icon: "", element: "EntrataMerce", path '/TestStagionatura/EntrataMerce' },
]

const getItemsMenu = () => {
    var children = []


    navigationItems.map(async (item) => {

               
        children.push(
            {
                path: item.path,
                lazy: () => import(`../pages/${item.element}`), //  Lazy load!
            },
        )
        
    })
  

    return children;
}

const configureRouters = () => {


    var router1 = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            Component: App,
            children: [
                {
                    path: '/',
                    Component: Layout,
                },
                {
                    path: '/TestStagionatura',
                    Component: Layout,
                    children: getItemsMenu(),
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            path: '/TestStagionatura/auth',
            Component: AuthLayout,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'login',
                    element: <Login
                        url={process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL_VALIDATE}
                        application={process.env.REACT_APP_API_APP_CODE} />,
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            path: '/TestStagionatura/NotAuthorized',
            element: <NotAuthorize description={'You do not have access for plant'} serviceName={'Seasoning Hams'} />
        },
    ]);


    return router1;
}

in app.js
    return (

        <AppProvider
            session={session}  
            authentication={authentication}
            navigation={NAVIGATION}
            branding={BRANDING}            
        >            
            <Outlet />            
        </AppProvider>
    );

in the index.js
const router = configureRouters();

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(  
    <Provider store={store}>
        <RouterProvider router={router} fallbackElement={<p>Loading...</p>} /> 
    </Provider>
);

in layout.js
 return (
     <Box>
         {isAccess  ?
             <DashboardLayout hideNavigation={false} slots={{ toolbarActions: Plant, sidebarFooter: SidebarFooter }}>
                 <Outlet />
             </DashboardLayout >

.......

Error verify:
Matched leaf route at location "/TestStagionatura/Dashboard" does not have an element or Component. This means it will render an <Outlet /> with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page. Error Component Stack
I want to load navigation.
I resolved and this is my solution:
In Layout.js I add
                 <Suspense fallback={renderLoader()}>
                    <Outlet />
                </Suspense>

and I load routing:
const getItemsMenu = () => {
var children = []


navigationItems.map(async (item) => {

           
    children.push(
        {
            path: item.path,                
            Component: lazy(async () => await import(`../pages/${item.element}`)),
        },
    )
    
})


return children;

}

Is this your exact code? For one, you are missing a colon after path on your second navigation item. And two notes on navigationItems.map(async (item) => {

map should be a foreach here, as you are not storing the result of the map, you are only creating a side effect.
an async callback within map will not be handled as you might expect


According to the doc React-Router/lazy
React-Router verion: 6.28.0 (you didn't say the version above)
It seems your lazy property, should be a async function. The code from document:
let dashboardRoute = {
  path: "dashboard",
  async lazy() {
    let { Layout } = await import("./pages/Dashboard");
    return { Component: Layout };
  },
  children: [
    {
      index: true,
      async lazy() {
        let { Index } = await import("./pages/Dashboard");
        return { Component: Index };
      },
    },
    {
      path: "messages",
      async lazy() {
        let { messagesLoader, Messages } = await import(
          "./pages/Dashboard"
        );
        return {
          loader: messagesLoader,
          Component: Messages,
        };
      },
    },
  ],
};

